# Taking the Angular2 starter app to production build

Tags: angular

After watching the ng-conf presentation on the Angular2 it appeared the Angular2 docs would be brilliant, and they are except on how to do a production build. All I can find is one line:

npm install dist --production

which didn't appear to work (I assumed it would build to a dist folder). Where are the details for building the production version?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SystemJS for module loader, then you can use SystemJS Builder, you can take a look for the setup in my [starter](https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular2-starter)

You can also bundle using Webpack, you transpile the TypeScript source code, and bundle them